# Finding saved YouTube videos from Firefox on OS X

Tags: macos, firefox

If you're using Firefox in OS X and watch a video on YouTube, is the video saved in a temporary folder somewhere? Where can it be found?

Answer (score 3):

On my system, it doesn't look like any `.flv` files get stored. Some Flash temporary files are stored in

`/private/var/folders/<randomname>/<YArandomname>/TemporaryItems/`,

but these files are deleted when the youtube pane is closed.

To find out where files are being stored on your system, I recommend [fseventer](http://download.cnet.com/fseventer/3000-2094_4-78566.html). As I have recommended it twice in 5 minutes, it might be appropiate to mantion that I'm not affiliated with fernlightning ;-)

If you want to save youtube videos, try out [DownloadHelper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/using-profiles.php).

Cheers!